# how to use sed with multiple meta characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to do this with sed

```
sed -i.bak 's,[href="#">bebeco.fr],href="http://www.bebeco.fr,http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco&eml-name=deme_faible&eemail={email}&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM&utm_medium=Targeting&utm_campaign=deme_faible&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men&utm_content=website">bebeco.fr,g' pour_test_demenagement-lien-faible.html
```

As you can imagine, due to the multiple meta characters, the sed command line is bugging and not changing the line.

What can I do to solve the problem and not put a `\` before each metacharacter?

Do you think `awk`can help, without going into programming?

TIA

Comment: There aren't multiple metacharacters in your expression.  The only metacharacters are `[`, `]`, and `.`, where it appears that you don't actually want to use `[` and `]` literally at all.

Comment: Oh, `&` in the replacement string needs to be escaped for unrelated reasons.  A bare `&` in the replacement gets replaced with the string which matched.

Comment: Because of the various syntax errors, it's not at all clear what you want to match and what to replace with.  Could you update your question to describe this in more detail?

Comment: Hi @tripleee, actually I wanted to replace `href="#">bebeco.fr` this. But as you can see, there is this `>`.

Comment: It's not a metacharacter.  It just matches itself literally.

Comment: @tripleee, I just realized what you were saying all along. `&` are not taken into account. duh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use a different separator. What about good old `~`? The data as shown does not contain the `~`:

```
sed 's~SEARCH~REPLACE~'
```

> Do you think awk can help, without going into programming?

:) Since `awk` is a programming language, I don't think it is possible without going into programming. However, I think sed is ok for that job.

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, indeed. It does the trick. What kind of separator do you have else than the ~ or the , ?

Comment: Pick one you like. As long as its not in the string you are looking for, anything goes. Check this: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-2

Comment: Btw, I expect more errors with your sed command. I cannot imagine that it works, since the search pattern looks strange... You are replacing every character out of `href="#">bco.r` by the replacement

Comment: aim is to replace this `href="#">bebeco.fr` by this `href="http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco&eml-name=deme_faible&eemail={email}&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM&utm_medium=Targeting&utm_campaign=deme_faible&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men&utm_content=website">bebeco.fr`

Comment: I personally would not use sed for that, I would use a programming language which supports dom manipulation. Regexes aren't suited to manipulate HTML

Comment: Which language would be suitable to deal with HTML manipulation for you, @hek2mgl?

Comment: What is the main purpose of your application? Is it just a shell script or part of a web application etc?

Comment: My application would be just to change some part of the html code into differents part like I've shown you. Something very basic so definitely a shell script.

Comment: I would use PHP since I've installed it on all my systems. However others would use Perl, Ruby or Python. Perl has the advantage that is is installed on all GNU/Linux systems. Others might need to get installed explicitely. Also you can use `xsltproc` for that. Probably the most elegant solution in a shell environment..

Comment: I've never done that before ... gloups. Do you have any guides where I can have a look?

Comment: I suggest to learn about XPath and XSLT first. They are like a swiss army knife for dom manipulation. Use their wikipedia pages to start.

Answer (score 2):

You are falling into the trap of thinking sed can operate on strings. It cannot. It operates on regexps with additional "special" characters. Just use awk as it does support string operations. Here's how to replace an old string with a new string:

```
awk -v old="original" -v new="replacement" 's=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))}1' file
```

It would be great if sed had a way to support strings like grep does with `-F` but it doesn't. It'd also be great if there was a briefer way to write it in awk but there isn't. So let's just suck it up and do string operations as provided by the tool that supports them instead of trying to find "special" characters that will sometimes work as delimiters and cobble together escape sequences to try to disable regexp metacharacters.

Comment: Thanks @ed-morton. So awk should do a better job then. Ok.

Comment: I bought the book I need to work through it http://www.amazon.fr/AWK-Programming-Language-Alfred-Aho/dp/020107981X/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1424785843&sr=8-5&keywords=awk

Comment: Yes awk is the tool that can do the job. I updated my answer to show how. That's too bad, you bought the wrong book. That one's very out of date, just sit it aside and don't bother to open it. The book to buy is Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033820.do.

Comment: Good one but it has its limits. I tried that `awk -v old="href="#">bebeco.fr" -v new="href="http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco&eml-name=deme_faible&eemail={email}&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM&utm_medium=Targeting&utm_campaign=deme_faible&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men&utm_content=website">bebeco.fr" 's=index($0,old){$0=substr($0,1,s-1) new substr($0,s+length(old))}1' test_Sofinco_v2.html > tmp && mv tmp test_bebeco_v2.html` and it gave me some errors. Most likely I will have to put characters to block the `"`.

Comment: Yeah, that's more of a limit on how do you specify a string. When you write a string as `"a"b"c"` where does it end? Assuming you want the double quotes around `b` to be part of the string your choices are to write it as `'a"b"c'` or `"a\"b\"c"` and you need to use the latter if you want it to include shell variables (or `'a"'"$shellvar"'"c'` if b is in shellvar which gets kinda hard to read).

Comment: I need 'a"b"c' or href="#">bebeco.fr

Answer (score 1):

Your regex syntax is hosed.  `[href="#">bebeco.fr]` matches a single character which is one of `h`, `r`, `e`, etc.  On top of that, you have three fields where `sed` only permits two, so it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish; but perhaps something like

```
sed -i.bak 's,href="#">bebeco.fr,href="http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco\&eml-name=deme_faible\&eemail={email}\&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM\&utm_medium=Targeting\&utm_campaign=deme_faible\&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men\&utm_content=website">bebeco.fr,g' pour_test_demenagement-lien-faible.html
```

That is, replace the hash in the double-quoted string in `href="#">bebeco.fr` with a long URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create and escaped pattern

```
MyStringSearch='ref="#">bebeco.fr'
MyStringSearchEsc="$( printf '%s' "${MyStringSearch}" | sed 's#\[]["\&*.\\/+?]#\\&#g' )"

MyStringReplace='href="http://mm.eulerian.net/dynclick/bebeco/?eml-publisher=bebeco\&eml-name=deme_faible\&eemail={email}\&eurl=https://www.bebeco.fr/?utm_source=ANIM\&utm_medium=Targeting\&utm_campaign=deme_faible\&utm_term=CCCC_seg_men\&utm_content=website">bebeco.fr'
MyStringReplaceEsc="$( printf '%s' "${MyStringReplace}" | sed 's#\[\\/\&"]#\\&#g' )"
```

before us it in final sed.

```
sed "s/${MyStringSearchEsc}/${MyStringReplaceEsc}/g"  pour_test_demenagement-lien-faible.html
```